# Something confusing in the proof of existence of simple sets in Soarse's book.

Tags: computability

In Soares's book he tries to prove that there's a simple set and I understand it well but there's something confuses me when he proves that the complement of $A$ is infinite he says that $\mathrm{card}(\text{complement of $A$ restricted to $2e$})\ge e+1$ therefore the complement of $A$ is infinite!!!!!
Or $A$ intersection $[0, 2i) \le i$ then the complement of $A$ is infinite!!
I cant figure out why it's infinite???
It's so confusing to me.
Please help if you can.
Thanks!

Comment: What is a simple set?

Comment: What is $A$ restricted to $2e?$  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format questions on this site.

Comment: Think about what happens as $e$ goes to infinity (or as $i$ goes to infinity) ...

Answer (score 0):

For every $e\in\Bbb N$, a subset of $A^\complement$ has cardinality $>e$, so $|A^\complement|>e$.